# Ionic 5 login with facebook, it only works with my facebook-email

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am developing an Ionic app with facebook login

```
(Ionic CLI: 6.10.0 - Ionic Framework: @ionic/angular 5.6.11 
Cordova CLI: 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1) - Cordova Platforms: android 8.1.0)
```

(It is in production mode in developers facebook), and the following happens:

When I test it on my mobile (Samsung A50, Android 11), with my facebook email, it works perfect, it connects and goes to the "menu" page.

When I install apk on another mobile (also Samsung A50, Android 11) and another facebook user / mail, if I delete chaché and data from the facebook application on the mobile, the Ionic app logs in and gives an error looking for data in the getUserDetail function. If I do not delete the cache and data of the facebook application on the mobile, it gives an error in the login directly.

I am attaching code (variables already defined before), I will appreciate the help you can give me, thank you very much

```
...
import { Facebook, FacebookLoginResponse } from '@ionic-native/facebook/ngx';
...


constructor(
    ...
    private fb: Facebook,
    ...
) {}

fbLogin() {
    this.fb.login(['public_profile', 'email'])
      .then(res => {
        if (res.status === 'connected') {
          this.isLoggedIn = true;
          this.getUserDetail(res.authResponse.userID);
        } else {
          this.isLoggedIn = false;
        }
      })
      .catch(e => console.log('Error logging into Facebook', e));
  }
  getUserDetail(userid: any) {
    this.fb.api('/' + userid + '/?fields=id,email', ['public_profile'])
      .then(res => {
        this.users = res;
        this.router.navigate(["/menu", this.users.email]);
      })
      .catch(e => {
        alert("Error getUserDetail");
      });
  }
```

Comment: What kind of error you get? 
      .catch(e => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(e));
      });

Comment: thanks, error 4201, User cancelled dialog